# Want to setup a lite server for drag and drop batch PDF converting

Tags: pdf, batch, adobe-acrobat, file-conversion

First off, how difficult / practical would this be? My company has a dept. that deals with hundreds of MSDS sheets daily and is looking for an affordable solution to converting batches of them. While Adobe Acrobat Pro does this, licences run ~$450 a piece.

I was hoping to grab an old machine an just run a headless server that users can drag batches of their .doc files (or whatever it might be) to a designated location and will be given back PDF forms. This way we limit any maintenance/possible issues to a single machine and simply map a network drive for them to use for this.

Possible? If so, how?

Comment: correction* a license is ~$180 per. However, dealing with 10+ users

Answer (score 2):

Open office has a built-in for this type of task:

```
oowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export doc_file.doc
```

So you could make a pretty simple linux server with a webpage, they upload their .doc and it uses the above to make a pdf.  Then your page would refresh and give the download link.  (Note, for LibreOffice, if you prefer it, use `lowriter` instead of `oowriter`.)

Of course, this is not bullet proof since sometimes OpenOffice/LibreOffice has some formatting issues.  It also isn't file extension agnostic - with imagemagick you could do most of the image extensions there.